# Turn off iMessage on computer but not on iPhone

Tags: macos, messages

I've recently bought a new Mac.

iMessage is on it. 
I'd rather not have it on my computer.  I want my texts to be kept private. 
How do I keep it on my iPhone and remove it from the Mac?

Answer (score 5):

In the Messages application on your Mac, go to

- Messages > Preferences > Accounts
- select your iMessage account
- uncheck the "Enable this account" checkbox that is below your Apple ID.